# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function get_option() views/includes/view.inc on line 2493

Tags: views

I installed the Carbide Builder Module from SooperThemes and now receive this error when trying to go to any node/add page.

Their support says one of my Views displays has a view with a missing display plugin.

I have a lot of views/displays. How can I find it easiest?

UPDATE: Looks like there are some old Views from a D6 installation uses Feeds.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the [Devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) and insert a [`ddebug_backtrace()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/ddebug_backtrace/8.x-1.x) statement before the line containing the `get_option()` method call. It should print out a stack trace that you can follow to some view id.